# linux + how to stop files creation under /var/spool/clientmqeueue

Tags: linux, spool

please advice how to stop the file creation under the directory -

```
   /var/spool/clientmqeueue
```

the reason for that because the clientmqeueue folder have huge capacity and files created every day

please advice for all possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your mail queue, most likely it's a program or programs sending mail(s) to users which your system doesn't know how to deliver.

you can check the output of `mailq` which may (or may not) show you what's in there, but *this command depends entirely on how your system is configured*.

As to what's generating them, it's most likely cron jobs.

Comment: please advice if I stop the service sendmail it will also to stop create files in this folder ?

Comment: _Most likely_ yes, but the better question is: _why aren't these emails being delivered in the first place?_

Comment: but after reboot service became start again , what we do in this case?

Comment: You need to disable it from starting on boot, but that is a different question and this is not the forum for it.  Perhaps start here: http://www.linux.org/forums/beginner-tutorials.53/

Comment: There are 2 mail queues. `/var/spool/clientmqueue` is where all client mails get queued. `sendmail` reads from this queue and places them in `/var/spool/mqueue` for delivery. Stopping `sendmail` will not stop any mail client from dropping mails into `/var/spool/clientmqueue`. You have to allow `sendmail` to process these mails. Or stop processes from sending mails in the first place.

Comment: Actually, `sendmail` places those files in `/var/mail/clientmqueue` prior to handing them off to the `MTA` (which may also be `sendmail`, but doesn't need to be.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about loosing all your emails, only to stop sendmail:

```
service stop sendmail
```

`/var/spool/clientmqueue` is where emails are waiting for delivery.
If there are problems with sendmail or it's configuration, this dir will be growing. Check your config files: `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` and `/etc/mail/submit.cf`